# How to check selected option, grab an array value and write its value in a div with the press of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The question might be a bit vague but I'll try to make sense.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="buttonholder">
    <button id="previous">< Previous round</button>
    <button id="next">Next round ></button>
    <button id="current">> Current round <</button>
<div style="font-size: 0;">
       <form id="inputform">

   <select name="rounds" id="selectbox">
    <option value="Round 1">--- Round 1 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 2">--- Round 2 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 3">--- Round 3 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 4">--- Round 4 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 5">--- Round 5 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 6">--- Round 6 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 7">--- Round 7 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 8">--- Round 8 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 9">--- Round 9 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 10">--- Round 10 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 11">--- Round 11 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 12">--- Round 12 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 13">--- Round 13 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 14">--- Round 14 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 15">--- Round 15 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 16">--- Round 16 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 17">--- Round 17 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 18">--- Round 18 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 19">--- Round 19 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 20">--- Round 20 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 21">--- Round 21 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 22">--- Round 22 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 23">--- Round 23 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 24">--- Round 24 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 25">--- Round 25 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 26">--- Round 26 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 27">--- Round 27 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 28">--- Round 28 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 29">--- Round 29 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 30">--- Round 30 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 31">--- Round 31 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 32">--- Round 32 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 33">--- Round 33 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 34">--- Round 34 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 35">--- Round 35 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 36">--- Round 36 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 37">--- Round 37 ---</options>
    <option value="Round 38">--- Round 38 ---</options>
    </select>

    <button id="submit">Go</button>
</form>
</div>
<div id="displayround">

</div>
</div>
```

And here is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

var round = new Array(); //The round displayed in the #displayround div
round[0]="1/38";
round[1]="2/38";
round[2]="3/38";
round[3]="4/38";
round[4]="5/38";
round[5]="6/38";
round[6]="7/38";
round[7]="8/38";
round[8]="9/38";
round[9]="10/38";
round[10]="11/38";
round[11]="12/38";
round[12]="13/38";
round[13]="14/38";
round[14]="15/38";
round[15]="16/38";
round[16]="17/38";
round[17]="18/38";
round[18]="19/38";
round[19]="20/38";
round[20]="21/38";
round[21]="22/38";
round[22]="23/38";
round[23]="24/38";
round[24]="25/38";
round[25]="26/38";
round[26]="27/38";
round[27]="28/38";
round[28]="29/38";
round[29]="30/38";
round[30]="31/38";
round[31]="32/38";
round[32]="33/38";
round[33]="34/38";
round[34]="35/38";
round[35]="36/38";
round[36]="37/38";
round[37]="38/38";

$("#buttonholder").find("button").addClass("left")
$("#buttonholder").find("#submit").removeClass("left").addClass("right")
$("#buttonholder").find("#inputform").addClass("right");

$("#displayround").text(round[0]).data('index', 0);

$("#next").click(function () {
   var index = +$("#displayround").data('index') + 1;
   if (index >= round.length) index = 0;
  $("#displayround").text(round[index]).data('index', index);
});

$("#previous").click(function () {
   var index = +$("#displayround").data('index') - 1;
   if (index <= -1) index = round.length - 1;
  $("#displayround").text(round[index]).data('index', index);
})

}); //end of document.ready function
```

Now what I want to happen is:

1. First you select a round from the selection box
2. You click the button "Go"
3. The text changes to the selected round in the "#displayround" by grabbing an array value

How do I achieve this with Jquery?

Comment: @Satpal http://jsfiddle.net/jLqq3/ Not sure if it works, let me know.

Comment: What should next, previous and current round click do? the text displayed in the div has to be 1/38 or the string?

Comment: @alecellis1985 I have a table beneath the buttons which I haven't included. The next button displays the next round in an ongoing football season, and adds new statistics etc. Which I doubt I will be able to do now that I have started working on the actual numbers themselves. Think I need to learn PHP to make it somewhat manageable lol..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `change` event

```
$('#selectbox').change(function () {
    //Extracted digit from the selected value
    var index = $(this).val().match(/\d+/) - 1;
    $("#displayround").text(round[index]).data('index', index);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/jLqq3/1/)

Additionally, I would suggest you to store index as the value .

### Edit

```
$('#selectbox').change(function () {
    //Extracted digit from the selected value
    var index = $(this) // Invoker of event or simply say element
    .val() //get selected value example Rouuld 10
    .match(/\d+/) - 1;  // /\d+/ is regular expression to get digits i.e. 10
    $("#displayround").text(round[index]).data('index', index);
});
```

Comment: suppose I will remove the button then to make it simple. Could you explain what the "(/\d+/) - 1; does exactly?

Comment: @DuploW, I have updated answer and tried to  provide explanation. However `/\d+/` is regular expression to get digits i.e. 10 from a string `Yahoo10`

Comment: Greatly appreciate it! I will have a read and try to understand everything.

Answer (score 0):

I added a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/jLqq3/1/)!
i think this will help you a lot and avoid a bit of coding:

I generated you the options with jquery so you dont have a big html
    
            < Previous round
            Next round >
            > Current round <
            
               
                
                    
                Go

in the js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
createComboBox(1,38,$( "select[name='rounds']"));
$("#buttonholder").find("button").addClass("left")
$("#buttonholder").find("#submit").removeClass("left").addClass("right")
$("#buttonholder").find("#inputform").addClass("right");

$("#displayround").text($("select[name='rounds']").val());

$("#next").click(function () {
  $("#displayround").text(displayValue(parseInt($("select[name='rounds']").val())+1));
});

$("#previous").click(function () {
  $("#displayround").text(displayValue(parseInt($("select[name='rounds']").val())-1));
})

$('#selectbox').change(function(){
    $("#displayround").text(displayValue($(this).val()));
});

$('#current').click(function () {
  $("#displayround").text(displayValue($('#selectbox').val()));
});
 });

    function displayValue(value)
{
    return value +'/38';
}
```

This functoin creates the comboBox

```
    function createComboBox(min,max,selector)
{
    var p;
    for(var i=min; i<max+1; i++)
    {
         p += '<OPTION VALUE='+i+'>'+'Round '+i+'</OPTION>';        
    }
    selector.append(p);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems it's to complicated javascript for me at the moment. Will save it and have it as sample code though :)

Comment: Just run the demo, it´s really simple if you debug it a bit. This will help you i guess